# React Native: Flatlist issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

The problem with my flatlist is that when i am scroll to the bottom and `onEndReached` is called it takes me back to the top of the list.
The expected behavior will be that it keeps the scroll distance and then add the items. The items are added in my case but like i said it takes me back to the top the list. This my code:

postList.js

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, FlatList, ListView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from './actions';
import { emptyData } from './actions';

class PostsList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.position = 0;
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.emptyData();
        this.props.fetchData(this.props.tabId, 0, this.props.dateFilter, this.position);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.dateFilter !== this.props.dateFilter || newProps.tabId !== this.props.tabId) {
            this.position = 0;
            this.props.emptyData();
            this.props.fetchData(newProps.tabId, 0, newProps.dateFilter, this.position);
        }
    }

    handleLoadMore = () => {
        this.position += 10;
        if (this.props.posts.data.total === this.props.posts.data.posts.length) {
            console.log("ALL LOADED")
            return
        }
        console.log("POSITION", this.position)
        this.props.fetchData(this.props.tabId, 0, this.props.dateFilter, this.position);

    };

    renderRow({ item }) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{item._id}</Text>
                <Image style={{ width: 200, height: 400 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
                <Text>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.posts.data.posts}
                    renderItem={this.renderRow}
                    onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
                    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                    extraData={this.props.posts.data.posts}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        posts: state.dataReducer,
        tabId: state.tabId,
        dateFilter: state.dateFilter
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchData: (type, filter, dateFilter, position) => dispatch(fetchData(type, filter, dateFilter, position)),
        emptyData: () => dispatch(emptyData())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsList)
```

home.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import  PostsList  from '../../postsList';
import * as actions from "../../actions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { TabView, TabBar, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View>
    <PostsList/>
  </View>
);

const initialLayout = {
  height: 0,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
};

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isData: true,
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: 'first', title: 'Todos' },
        { key: 'second', title: 'Encontrados' },
        { key: 'third', title: 'Perdidos' },
        { key: 'four', title: 'Adopción' },
        { key: 'five', title: 'Seguidos' },
      ]
    };

  }

  _renderTabBar = props => (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      scrollEnabled
      indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
      style={styles.tabbar}
      tabStyle={styles.tab}
      labelStyle={styles.label}
    />
  );

  _renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: FirstRoute,
    third: FirstRoute,
    four: FirstRoute,
    five: FirstRoute
  })

  _handleIndexChange = index => {
    this.props.selected_tab(index);
    this.setState({
      index,
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (

      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
        initialLayout={initialLayout}
      />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  tabbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#3f51b5',
  },
  tab: {
    width: 120,
  },
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffeb3b',
  },
  label: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
});

export default connect(null, actions)(Home);
```

The thing in home.js is that i use the same component for all my 5 tabs maybe it can cause a problem.

If you need more code please ask.Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I have a few ideas as to why it might be happening, in your onEndReached you are calling setState which would normally cause render on your whole screen which is probably why your FlatList is resetting, second FlatList is a pure component which means it causes a render when the props significantly change so if you pass something in the extraData prop of the FlatList it will only rerender when that particular value changes. I would suggest moving your position to a local variable instead of state and see if that helps.

Comment: is position is equivalent to the number of rows, which you want to fetch?

Comment: @NemiShah I updated my question using now the position like a local variable, is okay in that way? because it did not work be i think it should be that way it must be other thing the problem.And what can i put in extraData in the flatlist component?

Comment: @RajatGupta yes, position is the name i put to that

Comment: @FrancoCoronel im assuming this.props.posts.data.posts keeps increasing in size when a new set of posts is fetched, in that case you can use that as extradata as well. Also mapStateToProps also causes a re render when new data is consumed and passed to props, just a side note i thought might be worth knowing. Try extraData and see if that works.

Comment: @NemiShah I tried extraData={this.props.posts.data.posts} but it did not change the result. If you want you can check it out my project files is an open source project here is the url https://github.com/francoro/animals-react. I also added my home.js code to the answer maybe it have something to do.And the console gives me this error : VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {dt: 7862, prevDt: 589, contentLength: 7074.28564}

Comment: I clones your repo unfortunately it seems you havent committed your fetch logic so all the posts are coming undefined.

Comment: @NemiShah I made a commit and now it fetchs the posts you can check it out. Also i noticed that it happen the 90% of the times the thing that scrolls me up when i onEndReached. i scroll a few times slowly and i dont know if it has something to do but it keeps the position doing it like that but not always i can say the 10% of the times, that info maybe can help you to figure it out the problem

Comment: @NemiShah I created another repository without the bottom tabs that i added with react-router-flux and the tabs from the top.If you want to check it out https://github.com/francoro/flatlistRedux

Comment: @FrancoCoronel Hey sorry for the late reply got caught up at work, so I took a look at your original repo with the updated code and it seems that your redux setup that is causing your problem. So heres what I noticed, every time the api call was made your postList component would call willrecieveprops 5 times which is a lot, and the next time more posts are loaded it causes the entire screen to re render multiple times. I would suggest removing your api call from redux as it doesnt seem necessary.

Comment: @NemiShah It causes the rerender because postList it was in the configuration of the tabs that i declared 5 tabs and all use the same component so yes that can be bad but also if you look my new repository i removed the tabs its just one component now with the redux part and it render only once but the problem still persist. if you want you can check it out here  github.com/francoro/flatlistRedux . Thanks for the replies

Comment: @NemiShah I make it work i had to change 
concatResult.posts = action.initialData.posts.concat(action.newData.posts); 
for this:
concatResult.posts = state.data.posts.concat(action.newData.posts);

And also remove the data: [ ] from FETCHING_DATA. If you look my repository you will find it. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciated

Comment: @FrancoCoronel happy to help and glad you found the solution